# $K$ is compact to $X$ if and only $K$ is compact to $Y$ even if $X$ and $Y$ is not subset of one another?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Is the following statement true: $K \subset X$ and $K \subset Y$ such that $X \cap Y \ne \varnothing$ and $X \not\subset Y, Y \not\subset X$, then $K$ is compact relative to $X$ if and only if $K$ is compact relative to $Y$?

In Rudin's Chapter 2, and Theorem 2.33 states that: Suppose $K \subset Y \subset X$. Then $K$ is compact relative to $X$ if and only if $K$ is compact relative to $Y$. But is this embedding of $X$ and $Y$ necessary? What if $Y$ and $X$ is not subset of one another? I think this statement should still be true since compactness is an intrinsic property that does not depend on metric spaces? But I don't have enough techniques to prove it yet. Insights are appreciated!

Comment: If $K\subset X$ and $K\subset Y$, then $K\subset X\cap Y$.

Comment: @HowDoIMath Oh! So $K$ is compact relative to $X \cap Y$ if and only if $K$ is compact to $X$ or $K$ is compact to $Y$. Then using Theorem 2.33 again, indeed $K$ is compact to $X$ if and only if $K$ is compact to $Y$! Thank you so much!

Comment: Compactness is a topological property. That means it depends only on the topology on $K$, not what other spaces $K$ is a subspace. As long as $K$ has the same subspace topology from $X$ as it does from $Y$, then your statement is true. In particular if $K, X, Y$ are subspaces of a larger space $Z$, then it is true.